# Wait for the result of forEach before sending callback to main

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I want to collect the data with its child (another item which is bound to that product ID) 
I have a collection with this schema

```
// User Schema
const filtersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    filter_name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    filter_code:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    bind_to: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        default: null
    },
    filter_status:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    created_on:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated_on:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

If I enter a data to it, default bind_to value will be null, that means its parent. If I send the bind_to ID of a parent, it'll be ObjectID.

I want to collect data like this

```
[{
-- parent object --
children:[
  {
  -- child object --
  },
  {
  -- child object --
  }
]
}]
```

if we have more than one item it'll go through loop (forEach) but the callback is getting sent before the forEach loop getting finished. I know forEach is asynchronous and the request is synchronous. but confused about how to do that!

you can see the module below

```
// Get Filters by Parent ID
module.exports.getFiltersByParentId = (pid, callback) => {
    Filters.find({bind_to: pid}, callback);
}

//For getting the parent object and looping it to get its child objects
module.exports.getFilters = (callback, limit) => {
    Filters.find({bind_to: null}, (err, filters) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            let obj = {status: false, error: err.errmsg};
            callback(obj);
        } else {
            const resObj = [];
            filters.forEach(async function (ele) {
                await Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele._id, (err, cfil) => {
                    if (err) {
                        let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                        callback(obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log(ele, "Obj");
                        ele.children = cfil;
                        resObj.push(ele);
                    }
                });
            });
            Promise.all(resObj).then(res => {
                let obj = {status: true, data: res, message: "Filters found"};
                callback(obj);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

but in this case result object will be empty. how can I get the proper object with the values as mentioned above?

Even I tried with this method

```
const resObj = [];
            filters.map(function (ele) {
                Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele._id, (err, cfil) => {
                    if (err) {
                        let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                        callback(obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log(ele, "Obj");
                        ele.children = cfil;
                        resObj.push(ele);
                    }
                });
            });
            Promise.all(resObj).then(res => {
                let obj = {status: true, data: res, message: "Filters found"};
                callback(obj);
            });
```

And This

```
Promise.all(filters.map(function (ele) {
                Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele._id, (err, cfil) => {
                    if (err) {
                        let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                        callback(obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log(ele, "Obj");
                        ele.children = cfil;
                        resObj.push(ele);
                    }
                });
            })).then(res => {
                let obj = {status: true, data: res, message: "Filters found"};
                callback(obj);
            });
```

Ok, Now im returning a promise from `getFiltersByParentId`

```
module.exports.getFiltersByParentId = (pid, callback) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Filters.find({bind_to: pid}, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(results);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: `I know forEach is asynchronous and the request is synchronous` It's the other way around.

Comment: That question didn't help me! I checked that answer before asking here, there they are using a const array, It works fine with an array or even without that method call inside the forEach. but when I add that method it's not working. its sending empty array for the result of callback object!

Comment: You're trying to `await` inside a `forEach` - the `forEach` line will finish before the async operations finish, so `resObj` is empty. Use `.map` instead

Comment: I've tried with that, I updated the question with the method used, can you check it once!!

Comment: You need to return a Promise, right now the mapped array is just `undefined`s, look up how to convert a callback API to promises

Comment: should `callback(obj)` in the `if (err) {` block terminate the processing, or is `callback` expecting to be called multiple times in case of errors and success

Comment: also, does each iteration need to wait for the previous iteration to complete (i.e. `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` called in series) or should each `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` be run concurrently (i.e. parallel)?

Comment: yes, it should terminate if there is an error and `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` takes bind_to ID, we get it with the `ele` object which is parent object. with that parent ID we need to fetch the children of that parent!

Comment: so, callback will be called exactly once and once only  ... as to my second comment ... series or parallel

Comment: series. i just need to get all the parent data with its children. and return one array of object with all the parents

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` doesn't return a promise, there is no sense in `await`ing the response - so, I wrapped it in a new Promise - if I had time there's probably a simpler way to do this without bothering with async/await, since there's actually no promises at all in the code except for the promise no introduced to make use of async/await

Still, I believe the code is simpler to read this way, so, lets keep with the async/await and promise theme

Secondly, using `for ... of` loop makes the code very simple, especially since you want any error to cease further calls to `Filters.getFiltersByParentId`

code as follows

```
module.exports.getFilters = (callback, limit) => {

    Filters.find({bind_to: null}, async (err, filters) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            let obj = {status: false, error: err.errmsg};
            callback(obj);
        } else {
            const resObj = [];
            for (const ele of filters) {
                try {
                    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele._id, (err, cfil) => {
                            if (err) {
                                let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                                reject(obj);
                            } else {
                                console.log(ele, "Obj");
                                ele.children = cfil;
                                resolve(ele);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    resObj.push(result);
                } catch(e) {
                    return callback(obj);
                }
            }
            let obj = {status: true, data: resObj, message: "Filters found"};
            callback(obj);
        }
    });
};
```

edit: I had time :p

Here is the code without async/await, since there are no promises

```
module.exports.getFilters = (callback, limit) => {
    Filters.find({bind_to: null}, (err, filters) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            let obj = {status: false, error: err.errmsg};
            callback(obj);
        } else {
            const resObj = [];
            const getFilters = (index) => {
                if (index < filters.length) {
                    const ele = filters[index];
                    Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele._id, (err, cfil) => {
                        if (err) {
                            let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                            callback(obj);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            console.log(ele, "Obj");
                            ele.children = cfil;
                            getFilters(index + 1);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    let obj = {status: true, data: resObj, message: "Filters found"};
                    callback(obj);
                }
            };
            getFilters(0);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This I've tried just now, this won't respond only! here result will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Inside the method `Filters.getFiltersByParentId`, i've logged a object named 'Obj', there object is perfect. its fetching the data

Comment: I assumed `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` returned a promise because of your original code - I see now your original code was fundamentally flawed if `Filters.getFiltersByParentId` *does not return a promise* - I'd actually be surprised if it did now that I look at the fact that it takes a callback argument!

Comment: I've rewritten the answer

Comment: @rakcode - I've added an even better answer, since there are no Promises in your original code, only the ones you thought were there!

Comment: if there is a flaw in my code, how can I improve it? I'm new to nodeJS :p please help me to get better at it! thanks

Comment: do you read ALL the comments I made before you reply to the first one? @rakcode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190086/discussion-between-rakcode-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes to my question and using [@Jaromanda X's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) & [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) guide I came up with a solution for my question. it's not exactly as I wanted, but it's quite the same output.

I changed g`Filters.getFiltersByParentId` method to return Promise

```
module.exports.getFiltersByParentId = (pid, callback) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Filters.find({bind_to: pid._id}, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                let obj = {parent: pid, children: results};
                resolve(obj);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Then changed `forEach` to `array.map` and used promise array in `Promise.all` function

```
module.exports.getFilters = (callback, limit) => {
    Filters.find({bind_to: null}, (err, filters) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            let obj = {status: false, error: err.errmsg};
            callback(obj);
        } else {
            const resObj = [];
            var promises = [];

            filters.map(function (ele) {
                promises.push(Filters.getFiltersByParentId(ele, (err, cfil) => {
                    if (err) {
                        let obj = {status: false, message: err.errmsg};
                        callback(obj);
                    } else {
                        console.log(ele, "Obj");
                        ele.children = cfil;
                        resObj.push(ele);
                    }
                }));
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
                let obj = {status: true, data: res, message: "Filters found"};
                callback(obj);
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Finally, my output looks something like this

```
[
 {
  parent: {
   --- parent object ---
  },
  children: [
    {
     --- child object 1 ---
    },
    {
     --- child object 2 ---
    },
    {
     --- child object n ---
    }
  ]
 }
]
```